# mysqli_num_rows is 1 but mysql_fetch_assoc returns null

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am having a bit of an issue with a mysqli connection, seem to be falling at the first hurdle. Before going ahead, I have tested the connection and it working, the query is correct but a var_dump of the values in mysql_fetch_assoc and mysql_fetch_array are null.

The code checks to see if a row with the value exists, if it does it stops andif it doesn't then it pulls a value from the DB. This seems to be working fine up to the part of pulling the value.

Here is the code:

```
    db = new database('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'my_db');

    $db->query("SELECT * FROM `codes` WHERE `code` = '$ccode'");

    if ($db->numRows() == 0) 
    {
        echo "No value was found";

    }
    else
    {
        foreach($db->rows() as $email)
        {
            echo $email['um-email'];
            echo $ccode;
        }

    }


    $db->disconnect();   
}
```

Here is the code for the connection class page:

```
class database
{
protected $_link, $_result, $_numRows, $_content; 
public function __construct($server, $username, $password, $db)
{
    $this->_link = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $db);
    mysqli_select_db($this->_link, $db);
}

public function disconnect()
{
    mysqli_close($this->_link);
}

public function query($sql)
{
    $this->_result = mysqli_query($this->_link, $sql);

    echo $sql;

    $this->_numRows = mysqli_num_rows($this->_result);
}

public function content()
{
    return $this->_content;    
}




public function display_content()
{
    $arows = array();
    for($x = 0; $x < $this->numRows(); $x++)
    {
        $arows[] = mysqli_fetch_array($this->_result);
    }
    echo var_dump($arows);
    return $arows;
}

public function numRows()
{
    return $this->_numRows;
}

public function rows()
{
    $rows = array();
    for($x = 0; $x < $this->numRows(); $x++)
    {
        $rows[] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($this->_result);
    }
    echo var_dump($rows);
    return $rows;
}
}
```

At a real loss as to what is causing the issue, the fact that the DB has got value in there and is returning the number of rows, I don't understand why the arrays are null.

If the code examples above, I am trying to get the email address from the first code segment with this:

```
foreach($db->display_content() as $aemail)
    {
        echo $aemail['um-email'];
    }
```

Ultimately that will be assigned to a session variable for later for the time being I am using echo to see if it has a value. For the moment there are bits that could be protected from SQL injection but I would like to get this working before adding validation.

The exact message returned from the var_dump is:

```
array (size=1)
0 => 
array (size=3)
  'ID' => string '3' (length=1)
  'code' => string '12345' (length=5)
  'um_email' => string 'billybob@bobmail.com' (length=20)
```

For the TL;DR number of rows is 1 when there is a correct value, mysqli_fetch_array/assoc return null.

Many thanks I appreciate all of the help

UPDATE: Removed the line as suggested by Mark Baker and now it seems the data is now being store in the array (looking at the var_dump) however I am now receiving an " Undefined offset: 0" value.

Comment: Don't do `$this->_content = mysqli_fetch_array($this->_result);` in your db `query()` method, because your `display_content()` method is ignoring the fact that you've already fetched the first row into `$this->content`.... and it will also cause you problems if the query doesn't return any rows

Comment: Hi, thanks for the tip, I have removed that line and it seems to be pulling the data into the array however I am now receiving an error about an unindentified index for the value

Comment: Hi Undefined_variable, I have just tried that now however I am still having the same issue and it is still not displaying the value

Comment: Try var_dump($aemail) in your for loop

Comment: Hi, I have posted the output from the var_dump towards the end, as you can see it is picking up the values but it isn't outputting them now

Comment: it is not in your foreach loop...check var_dump($email) in for loop...

Comment: var_dump of $email in the foreach loop is returning null

Answer (score 0):

Bit of an old question and has been resolved, I redesigned the form and the database connections, turned out after handling this form I needed to use the array position instead of the name of the field.